# Advanced Templates/Snippets for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with Resharper 8.1 installed and I'm all about finding shortcuts for regular tasks.  One such task that I do regularly is add new constructor dependencies to MVC Controllers.  So for example, I might have the following:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private readonly ICustomerManager _customerManager;

    public MyController(ICustomerManager customerManager) {
        _customerManager = customerManager;
    }
```

Now I want to add in an IOrderManager, so I have 3 different lines to adapt: I have to add a private variable to store it, add a parameter to the constructor, and add a line inside the constructor to set the private variable.

I'd love to be able to write a macro/template/snippet that would allow me to enter "IOrderManager" and have it add all the code for me.  Is there any way I can do this in VS2013 or Resharper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to add the field manually, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and let ReSharper initialise the field from the constructor. It will add the parameter, and initialise the field with it.